Is it Possible to Install Print Server Role Inside a Windows Server Core 2019 Container?
I'm currently working with a Windows Server 2019 VM and considering setting up a containerized environment for a label printing service. My goal is to create a container with the print server role using Windows Server 2019 Core (mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019).
I have encountered some issues:

Is it possible to install and configure a print server role in a Windows Server 2019 Core  container?

I attempted to install the required features using Windows commands, but I'm encountering errors.
I also tried installing Chocolatey inside the container to simplify the process, but I wasn't able to get it installed.
Additionally, I have another VM running Windows Server 2022, and I tried a similar setup there. On the Windows Server 2022 VM, I installed a container using Windows Server 2022 Core and managed to install Chocolatey. However, I still couldn't install the Print Server role feature.
I also experimented with a different image (mcr.microsoft.com/windows:ltsc2019), and in that environment, I was able to install the Print Server service. However, this image isn't what I need for my project, as I specifically require the Windows Server 2019 Core  environment.
Has anyone successfully set up a Print Server in a Windows Server 2019 Core container?
If so, could you provide guidance or share the steps that worked for you?
Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

I've already attempted to install the required features using Windows commands, but I'm encountering errors. What errors?

Hello,
Error bellow,
PS C:> Install-WindowsFeature -Name Print-Server
Install-WindowsFeature : The request to add or remove features on the specified server failed.
Installation of one or more roles, role services, or features failed.
The source files could not be found.
I'm not sure how to solve this. Ideally, I would like to get the Print Server role working inside this Server Core container if possible. If not, i have to see other ways to solve.
Apologies for not including the errors in my previous messages, and thanks in advance for any assistance.

The Print Server role is available on Server Core editions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-core/server-core-roles-and-services.
However, it's not available in Server Core containers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-core/server-core-container-removed-roles.
N.B. Chocolatey has nothing to do at all with Windows built-in roles and services; it's used to install additional packages, not system features.

In one of those links, it mentions:
"The way we've done this is by optimizing the architecture and removing things you don't need in a Server Core container. Some were things that didn't work in containers, some were roles and features no one's been using."
Does this mean that I'm completely unable to install the Print Server role? I understand they might have removed it for optimization, but is there still a way to install it if needed? I'm just trying to get a better understanding of the situation!
Again, thanks for the help

@RodrigoMorais the Print Server role is not available in a container. You need a real Windows Server (Core or not) to use it.

A container image is different from a Windows Server image. It's built to be as lightweight as possible. Microsoft removed as much as possible from it in order for it to be as small as possible. The Print Server role just isn't there.
